# How to change PDF format from A4 to Us Letter using html2pdf?

Tags: php, html2pdf

I'm trying to change PDF format from A4 to US LETTER using html2pdf with PHP but I didn't get it.
I tried to define width and height instead of A4 but it didn't work.
Any solution, please?

```
$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', array($width_in_mm,$height_in_mm), 'fr', 'true', 'UTF-8', [0, 10, 0, 5]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the answer. You need to use 'USLETTER' instead of 'A4'.

Comment: You should mark your reply as the correct answer, that way others with the same question can find it more easily.

Comment: "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in." https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Please also update your answer to include a code snippet to show _where_ you need to add `USLETTER`, in order to help other people with the same problem :)

Comment: I will accept my own answer after 2 days. thank you